# FLEX: How to set the scene`s background color in Flare3d?

Tags: apache-flex, flare

How to set the scene`s background color in Flare3d?

Comment: Your question currently lacks too many details I think, what SDK are you using specifically what version of Flare3D are you using what platform are you attempting to deploy to, what's the container used for the content generated for the Flare3D component???

Comment: I use the FLEX SDK 4.5.1 and Flare3d 2.0 prerelease, it only containd two 3d scene class, Viewer3D and Scene3D(Which the former is the subclass of the latter)

Comment: Does this work for you? sorry i don't have time to test it right now http://flare3d.com/docs/flare/basic/Scene3D.html#clearColor I'm looking at 3D engines myself now so I may start trying to implement some things using Flare3D as it seems a viable option, other ones I'm looking at are Alternativa3D and Unity3D.

Answer (score 0):

scene.backgroundColor = 000000